# Defining the Metric for a Standard Parametrization of a Cylinder

Tags: differential-geometry

This is very simple. Consider a cylinder in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. Let the axis of the cylinder coincide with the $z$-axis. Allow the cylinder to be paramterized as follows:
\begin{align*}
x(\varphi,h) &= a \cos \varphi \\
y(\varphi,h) &= a \sin \varphi \\
z(\varphi,h)&= h \\
\end{align*}
The metric $g$ for this surface is 
\begin{equation*}
g = a^{2} \text{d}\varphi^{2} + \text{d}h^{2}
\end{equation*}
How do we know this is the metric? Like, derive it for me please from the given parameterization. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $g_{\mathbb{R}^3} = da^2+a^2d\phi^2+dh^2$?

Comment: I have no idea because I don't understand how to derive it. I may very well have it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $(a,\phi,h) = (\theta^1,\theta^2,\theta^3)$. Write

$$dx = \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta^i}d\theta^i\ \ dy = \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta^i}d\theta^i\ \ dz = \frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta^i}d\theta^i \tag{1}$$

we are using [Einstein Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) in (1).

Compute $dx^2$, $dy^2$ and $dz^2$.

Finally the metric is given by $$g_{\mathbb{R}^3} = dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$$

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have any questions.

Comment: That was very helpful. I'm new to tensors and didn't organized the problem neatly. Once I saw how nicely you laid it out with the Einstein summation convention it was straightforward to solve. Must remember: when working with tensors, don't lose track of my indices!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. You may use the same approach to find other metrics as well. That's right!

Answer (score 3):

If you choose the usual Euclidean (Pythagorean) metric, then the metric tensor (and its pull-back to cylindrical coordinates) is $g=dx^2+dy^2+dz^2=\\(\cos\phi da-a\sin\phi d\phi)^2+(\sin\phi da+a\cos\phi d\phi)^2+(dh)^2=\\da^2+a^2d\phi^2+dh^2.$

Comment: This should be the chosen answer. The question is asking how we find the pullback of the Euclidean metric to the cylindrical coordinate system